# appending css3 @keyframes won't work in safari

Tags: jquery, css

this is tricky to explain so forgive me if i ramble a bit.

with js/jquery i am creating a style to append to the document header once i can determine that width of the element that will contain the animation.  for instance, i have some clouds that slide across the sky so i need to know how wide the viewport is so they cover the entire screen with the animation.  once i have the style variable defined (style) i am appending the head element with it like this:

```
$('html > head').append(style);
```

this works perfectly in chrome and firefox but safari straight up refuses to work.  i tried it a slightly different way:

```
$('head').append('<style type="text/css">*@keyframe attributes here*</style>');
```

again, works fine in chrome and firefox but safari doesn't see it.  before you ask, yes, i am using the -webkit- vendor prefix and yes, it's listed before the non-vendor specific @keyframes attribute :)

so then i tried the jquery keyframes plug-in with the exact same result.  it works perfectly in chrome and firefox but not safari.  but ONLY with the keyframes.

i have searched and searched for anyone else with this issue but all i can find are countless threads about making sure to use the proper vendor prefixes in the proper sequence (which i have done).

if i hardcode the keyframes into the css file they work fine but obviously that does me no good as i cannot specify the proper width for the animations.  i need to work on widths (not %) because of looping animations and offsets (it's complicated).

*EDIT*
here is a sample of the style var that i am appending to the header.  perhaps safari is particular about the formatting?

```
<style>
@-webkit-keyframes charmove { from { -webkit-transform : translateX(0px); } to { -webkit-transform : translateX('+winWidth+'px); }}
@keyframes charmove { from { transform : translateX(0px); } to { transform : translateX('+winWidth+'px); }}
</style>
```

i tried it, also, without adding the -webkit- on the transform element as well.  same result.

Comment: yup.  i did that as well.  tried it both ways.

Comment: I don't suppose your using razor view engine, or getting any console errors?

Comment: no errors in console.  it's just ignoring the appended rules.

Comment: Only other possibility that I can think of is a delegatation issue. But to say that, you'd have to show your markup to see how it's defined.

Comment: i suppose but it seems odd that it would ONLY affect the @keyframes and no other css property.  and it also works fine in firefox and chrome.  i know that doesn't always mean it's 100% correct but it seems to me that safari might have a bug here...

Comment: could you post a fiddle that reproduces this issue?

Comment: when i created the fiddle i decided to test an extremely simplified version of my code and i discovered something very interesting.

when i do nothing but create the style variable and append it to the head it works fine in safari.  the MOMENT that i try to use jquery to determine the width of the div the animation sits in, safari shuts off.  i output the value of the style and and the var for width and safari reads them just fine, but the append breaks.

makes NO sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i figured it out (and got some more gray hairs!)

turns out, safari won't read short-hand animation properties when you define them on the element you're animating.

so instead of:

```
-webkit-animation: 5s *name-of-anim* infinite linear;
```

you have to do:

```
-webkit-animation-name: charmove;
-webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
```

i had tried that previously (early on in this nightmare) but it didn't work.  i guess i must have done something ELSE wrong while testing it because it's working now.

hopefully this post can help someone else that might struggle with this issue since google was basically NO help.

:)

Comment: i should also add something i just discovered.  i had included the jquery.keyframes plug-in to test if it would work (it didn't, at the time).  the odd thing is that i am not using anything from that js file but unless i include it on the page, the animations do not work in safari.  no clue why (or even how it's possible) but it's what i'm seeing here.